# ngOnInit and Constructor not called while navigated from previous page using router.navigate

Tags: angular, ionic4

In ionic 4 framework, I have navigate to the page using router.navigate. In the navigated page, constructor and ngOnInit are not called from second time. First time only called.

Comment: Please share your code to review

Comment: Try https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-lifecycle-events/

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit() Fired once during component initialization.I think your page is child one.Child component will destroy only when its parent component destroys.Thats why constructor and ngOninit not calling second time.In addition to the Angular life cycle events, Ionic Angular provides a few additional events, you can use that

```
ionViewWillEnter() - Fired when the component routing to is about to animate into view.  
ionViewDidEnter() - Fired when the component routing to has finished animating.  
ionViewWillLeave() - Fired when the component routing from is about to animate.  
ionViewDidLeave() - Fired when the component routing to has finished animating.
```

for more details :- https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Comment: No. My page is not a child. I have few menus and all are parent. While navigating from one menu to other menu, Constructor and ngOnInit not called. This is for except one page which called both Constructor and ngOnInit.